# Opening another port for mysql incoming connection, on centos7

Tags: mysql, centos7

I installed MySQL server on a new Centos7 server and I wanted to add it as an instance for a MySQL workbench. It works fine with port 3306, but my web app needs it to work with port 3307.

How do I change the port? I have already tried editing `/etc/my.cnf` by adding the following:

```
[client]
port = 3307

[mysqld]
port = 3307
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happened after you changed the port? Have you even restarted `mysqld`? We need symptoms, please provide all the required info, not just 20%.

Comment: Thank you @Mjh for your kind reply

Sure,

mysqld service could not restart, without any message.

Comment: @Mjh

Adding the /my.cnf file before.
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: Hi
I tried using 

sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 3307

the port won't update and 

sudo /usr/sbin/semanage port -l | grep mysql

output is the same as before.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, since my server is on AWS I was forced to create an SSH Key
about AWS ssh keys: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/generate_ssh_key.html)
I used putty gen to create the key: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-ssh-keys-with-putty-to-connect-to-a-vps)

After the key creation I added a new instance to MySQL workbench with 
the address, MySQL server user, and the new certificate key I created in SSL connection.
dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html